# How to set a template for a cell in DataGrid in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I have a data grid which `ItemsSource` is binded to the result of LINQ to Entity query and in one column are `EntityCollection` objects.

```
   private void DataGridRecipientsLoad()
    {
        dataGridRecipients.ItemsSource = from rec in _recipientService.GetAllRecipients()
                                         select rec;
        dataGridRecipients.Columns[7].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        dataGridRecipients.Columns[8].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;            
    }
```

How can I create a template in C# that takes out just string properties out of the items in `Entity Collection` and displays them? Right now the cells are empty.

The `EntityCollection` consists entities called `MailingList` and I want to display `myMailingList.Name` of each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have collection of customers and of them has the next properties: `FirstName` and `LastName`:

```
internal class Customer
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

then you can simple grid view for it:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CustomersGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And you also need to assign `ItemSource` (as you did in you code).
You can also write more flexible templates for your need using `DataGridTemplateColumn`.
I suggest you read more about xaml templates. (this [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)/[another link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/19/wpf-datagrid-stock-and-template-columns.aspx) has nice samples).
p.s.Also when i see such questions i allways suggest to read about [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).